# JSON vs. Object to store settings

Tags: javascript, json, object

For my project I need to store some settings during the session. For this I build up a JSON Object like this:

```
var oSettingsJSON = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oSettingsJSON.setData({
        "partially_search": "true",
        "case_sensitive": "true",
        "aSearchResults" : [],
        "indexOfSearchResults": "0",
        "searchedText": "",
        "showId": "true"
    });
```

So, now I got the idea to store this data in an object, becaus then I needn't to write every time `model.getProperty(property)` or `model.setProperty(property, value)`.I understand JSON and objects, it's only about a best practiceor something to handle settings. What is more often used in the real world,or doesn't it matter what to use?

Comment: I usually store the settings as JSON, but convert it to an Object when using it in JavaScript (`JSON.parse()`, `JSON.stringify()`)

Comment: Thanks for this fast comment :) Yeah, it is an object I use the JSONModel class from sapui5 to store it,

Comment: By the way, if this is one users settings for your website, you may want to consider using something like `localStorage` instead. e.g. `localStorage.setItem("partially_search", "true");` `localStorage.getItem("partially_search"); //"true"`. This is then accessable from all pages in your site.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But it's only for one page

Comment: I don't see why you can't just create your JSON object and call it as `oSettingsJSON["partially_search"]`

Answer (score 1):

JSON stands for Javascript Object Notation. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/json/). Basically, if you want to store data inside a Javascript Object, then you should use JSON, since it is very simple to comprehend/use and there is virtually no server application technology without a parser for it. Since you are already using Javascript, JSON is recommended.

For instance this is a JSON object:

```
{
    "partially_search": "true",
    "case_sensitive": "true",
    "aSearchResults" : [],
    "indexOfSearchResults": "0",
    "searchedText": "",
    "showId": "true"
}
```